# Can search functionality require enter key to execute?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Regarding the Find functionality in Visual Studio Code, can it be configured so that you have to hit Enter/Return to execute the search?    That way, your cursor position won't change unless an exact match is found for the complete search string

Answer (score 3):

Yes, disable this setting:

`Editor > Find: Cursor Move On Type`

The cursor will not move to the next match until you <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Are you sure it's not phrased differently?  I can't find that setting anywhere in VS Code preferences -> settings -> text editor (Mac version)

Comment: That is definitely it.  I'm on W10 but I doubt that makes any difference for this setting.  Gear Icon (lower left) / Settings => type `Cursor Move` into the input at the top.

Comment: Perhaps this was a new setting that was added in the last year?  I realized I'm stuck on a corporate installed version of VSCode 1.46.1 that is a year old and offers no way to be updated

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/60977 It was added in v1.49 so that is your issue.  [BTW, some security updates have occurred in the meantime as well.]